# c# Problems with datagrid

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have an event that triggers upon a treeview node click, this then creates a datagridview and adds it to a panel:

```
void tvd_NodeClickEvent(double animal, string experiment, string pluginIdentifier)
    {

        DataGridDisplay dgv = new DataGridDisplay(panel4);
        dgv.addDatagrid(animal, experiment, pluginIdentifier);

    }
```

I try to remove the old datagrid by doing the following:

```
panel4.Controls.Remove(datagrid);
        panel4.Invalidate();
```

And then adding the new datagrid:

```
 panel4.Controls.Add(datagrid);
```

The problem is, the datagrids are drawing themselves on top of eachother without removing the old one?  Any ideas?

Thanks.

EDIT:  Extra Code added

```
void ConfigureDatagrid()
    {
        datagrid.Resize += new EventHandler(datagrid_Resize);

        panel4.Controls.Remove(datagrid);
        panel4.Invalidate();
        datagrid.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 40);
        panel4.Controls.Add(datagrid);

        columnsWidth = datagrid.Columns.GetColumnsWidth(DataGridViewElementStates.Visible);

        checkDatagridControls();

        datagrid.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Both;
        datagrid.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Right);
        datagrid.Dock = (DockStyle.Top);

        AdjustDatagridHeight();
        AdjustDatagridWidth();

        datagrid.RowHeadersVisible = false;

        datagrid.AutoResizeColumnHeadersHeight();

    }
```

The code above is called once a new datagrid has been obtained as such:

```
datagrid = file.returnDatagrid(mouse, experiment);
        ConfigureDatagrid();
```

The panel is passed through from the Winform into the datagrid class.

Comment: Please show the code in situ where you are removing the existing datagrid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not complete. What do "datagrid" refer to exactly and how is it initiated/disposed ? in your event ? Then why don't you handle removal/adding there ?

```
panel4.Controls.Remove(datagrid);
panel4.Controls.Add(datagrid);
```

What you are basically doing here is just removing the element and then adding it back again.
You should call the first line before your event, and you're done I think.

Besides, I think you are not doing things properly : Why Remove/Add your DGV anyway and replace it by the same components. It should NOT be this way. since it appears that you are handling the same type of data, then you should affect the DataTable only whithout touching  the DataGridView

EDIT :

According to your edit and comments, this should make more sense :

```
panel4.Controls.Remove(datagrid);
datagrid=file.returnDatagrid();
panel4.Controls.Add(datagrid);
panel4.Invalidate();
```

Comment: Thanks, I have it working now.  The reason I do it this way with the new datagrid, is because depending on what node the user clicks on, the datagrid could be completely different.  The datagridviews are obtained from a number of plugin dll's that populate the datagrid from a dataset, but then also add things like check columns in certain places, etc and they vary greatly between dll's so I can't just have on datagrid object on the client machine that is updated with different datasets.  Unless you know of a different way - I would be grateful to hear it.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: I have faced a similar issue and my advice is that you really should avoid the use of heterogeneous dll's. Populating a datagrid should be generic and straighfroward. but FIRST OFF, as a rule of thumb, Please be very careful to SEPARATE Data Logic from Presentation Logic. In your case the two seem very tightened and this is problematic : Deal with each issue (Data/Prez) separately it will be much cleaner and maintainable. If you want to add specific behaviour to your DGV on different nodes, it is possible, with the same component, adjusted to fit the needs of your presentation when needed.

Comment: Hi Mika,  Apologies for the delayed response - I have just noticed your reply. What do you mean regarding the seperation of data/pres in this instance.  In my case, a click on the treeview node, obtains the data from a database in an xml format, it then populates a datatable and then into the datagrid.  Is this incorrect?  Thanks.

Comment: I mean, whatever is the source and nature of your data, it should not affect your datagrid. Your presentation logic should be independent of the process of data retrieval. You see, you are calling your ConfigureDatagrid method on and on, and affecting your panel, removing/adding the dg, whenever you retrieve your Data. In my sense, this is a very poor design you should find a way to do this in a cleaner and smoother way, separately and independently.

Comment: And on top of all, try avoiding to alter your panel/dg. Instead, just change the binding and datatables.

Answer (score 1):

You're removing and readding the same `datagrid`:

```
    panel4.Controls.Remove(datagrid);
    panel4.Invalidate();
    datagrid.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 40);
    panel4.Controls.Add(datagrid);
```

nowhere in this code do you update `datagrid` so you are trying to remove something that doesn't exist in `Controls` and then adding it.

You need to get your **old** `datagrid` to pass to `Remove` or remove it before update the variable:

```
    panel4.Controls.Remove(datagrid);
    datagrid=file.returnDatagrid();
    datagrid.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 40);
    panel4.Controls.Add(datagrid);
    panel4.Invalidate();
```

Comment: The datagrid is changed with datagrid=file.returnDatagrid() as above.  Should I remove the old datagrid before obtaining the new one, is that what you are saying?

Comment: @Darren - yes. That is indeed what I am saying.